# relm4 - Access nested template child from root

Tags: rust, gtk4

I have a main WidgetTemplate view, which includes another WidgetTemplate inside of it:

```rust
adw::Window {
    // ...

    #[template]
    MainWidget {

        #[template_child] // Can't access MainWidget->SettingsPage->btn_dark_mode like this
        btn_dark_mode {
            connect_clicked => Message::DarkMode,
        },

    },
}
```

Here is the `MainWidget` template:

```rust
#[relm4::widget_template(pub)]
impl WidgetTemplate for MainWidget {
    view! {
        gtk::Box {
            set_orientation: gtk::Orientation::Vertical,

            gtk::Stack{
                    set_margin_all: 11,
                    set_margin_top: 7,

                    #[template]
                    add_child = &SettingsPage {} -> {
                        set_name: "settings",
                    },

                    #[template]
                    add_child = &MainPage {} -> {
                        set_name: "main",
                    },
                }

        }
    }
}
```

And inside of the `SettingsPage` template, there is a button which should send a Message:

```rust
#[relm4::widget_template(pub)]
impl WidgetTemplate for SettingsPage {
    view! {
        gtk::Box {
            set_orientation: gtk::Orientation::Vertical,
            set_spacing: 3,

            #[name = "btn_dark_mode"] // I NEED TO HANDLE connect_clicked OF THIS WIDGET FROM ROOT VIEW
            gtk::Button {

                #[wrap(Some)]
                set_child = &gtk::Image {
                    set_icon_name: Some("night-light-symbolic"), // When this clicked, I need to send Message::DarkMode
                },

            },
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**: Basically I want to handle connect_clicked of btn_dark_mode. I couldn't write directly on the template because it doesn't have the `sender`. I need to declare it on main `view!` but I can't access a template_child of a template_child from main `view!`.

How can I do this?